# asterisk - get dtmf during call phpagi

Tags: asterisk, dtmf

I am using asterisk with phpagi - I want create a variable $pressedsomething = TRUE; if the called party pressed something while they are talking. I've been looking around and do not know where to start. Please keep in mind, I want the DTMF from the callee side not from my end...

Any kind of help I can have with this is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that from AGI. But you can do that using features.conf

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+config+features.conf

Comment: I still don't get it. Can you please help me understand what you're trying to say? I understand that with features.conf you can set/allow the callee to hang themselves up by hitting certain buttons... but here; i just want to be notify that the callee did press something in a veriable....

Comment: You can't do "just want to be notify" in AGI. for notify see features.conf or asterisk events

Comment: that is such a bummer! I was hoping AGI can do this for me :( would made my app so wonderful :(

Comment: You can put event listener to got DTMF. or use EAGI(hi cpu load)

Comment: I'm really a newbie at this, but pretty much, I have a hangup agi script, and in that hangup script, I just want to update a mysql table if any dtmf was pressed from the callee side.... any kind of help towards that direction is greatly appreciated

Comment: Read this : http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/asterisk+manager+events  http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+config+features.conf . Unfortanly no easy way do what you asking. Probably you have hire hi-skilled expert or think how do your app other way.